# ProgressBar and mouse clicked event

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have a Label and a ProgressBar in a GridPane.
I've registered an onMouseClicked-event handler on the GridPane.
If I click on the Label the handler gets triggered.
If I click on the ProgressBar the handler doesn't get triggered. 
Why? How can I fix it?

```
package test;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class ProgressBarTestApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        ColumnConstraints columnConstraints0 = new ColumnConstraints();
        columnConstraints0.setHgrow(Priority.SOMETIMES);
        ColumnConstraints columnConstraints1 = new ColumnConstraints();
        columnConstraints1.setHgrow(Priority.NEVER);
        gridPane.getColumnConstraints().addAll(columnConstraints0, columnConstraints1);

        RowConstraints rowConstraints0 = new RowConstraints();
        rowConstraints0.setVgrow(Priority.SOMETIMES);
        gridPane.getRowConstraints().add(rowConstraints0);

        Label someLabel = new Label("Some Label:");
        ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar();
        progressBar.setPrefWidth(250.0d);
        someLabel.setLabelFor(progressBar);
        gridPane.add(someLabel, 0, 0);
        gridPane.add(progressBar, 1, 0);
        gridPane.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
        gridPane.setHgap(5.0d);
        gridPane.setOnMouseClicked(event -> System.out.println("Clicked!"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(gridPane, 350, 150);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: The handler is evoked if you click anywhere _but_ the `ProgressBar`. I don't know why. It works everywhere if you add the same handler directly to the `ProgressBar`.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that the `MouseEvent` is being consumed. I had a quick look through the `ProgressBar` class and it would seem that the `ProgressIndicatorSkin`'s `BehaviourBase` may be causing the event to be consumed.

A quick and dirty solution would be to set the mouse clicked `EventHandler` for the `ProgressBar` to re-fire the event to the `GridPane`:

```
progressBar.setOnMouseClicked(e -> gridPane.fireEvent(e));
```

or to work with any `Parent` node:

```
progressBar.setOnMouseClicked(e -> progressBar.getParent().fireEvent(e));
```

or subclass `ProgressBar` to automatically apply this behavior:

```
public class NoConsumeProgressBar extends ProgressBar {

    public NoConsumeProgressBar() {
        setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            Parent parent = getParent();
            if (parent != null) {
                parent.fireEvent(e);
            }
        });
    }    
}
```